# Multiple word phrase in simple_query_string search doesn't return highlight data, but does with any non-zero slop

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, aws-elasticsearch

I have a peculiar highlight behavior occuring when using a simple_query_string, with any highlighter (plain, unified, fvh)

1. Highlights working when simple query string is using terms (not phrases):
   [Working when just terms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Tnp.png)
2. Highlights stop working when you close the quotations, effectively making Regular Meeting a phrase:
   [Not working at all when searching as a phrase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3VTe.png)
3. But if I add slop of anything more than 0 to the previously not working phrase it works fine again, albeit with the wrong result set since I didn't want slopped results:
   [Works fine if I slop however](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DSJN.png)

When using direct API requests the highlight key disappeares entirely in the result when searching a phrase with zero slop (or slop not defined, leading to the behavior in the second step above.

I have tried overriding the highlight query as well, same exact problem. Here is the query I am using in these examples, I've also directly replicated this behavior with hardcoded strings and API calls:

```
        "query": {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": query,
            "fields": ["title", "content"]
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "fields": {
            "title": {},
            "content": {}
          }
        }
```

The field in question (title, content) for highlights has mappings as follows:

```
"properties" : {
    "content" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "autosuggest" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "autosuggest_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "ngram_search_analyzer"
        },
        "delimiter" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "index_options" : "offsets",
          "analyzer" : "universal_delimiter_analyzer"
        },
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "lang" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "universal"
        },
        "synonyms" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "synonyms"
        }
      },
      "analyzer" : "standard",
      "index_prefixes" : {
        "min_chars" : 1,
        "max_chars" : 12
      },
      "index_phrases" : true
    },
    "title" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "autosuggest" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "autosuggest_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "ngram_search_analyzer"
        },
        "delimiter" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "index_options" : "offsets",
          "analyzer" : "universal_delimiter_analyzer"
        },
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "lang" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "universal"
        },
        "synonyms" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "synonyms"
        }
      },
      "analyzer" : "standard",
      "index_prefixes" : {
        "min_chars" : 1,
        "max_chars" : 12
      },
      "index_phrases" : true
    },
    ...
```

Finally, here is the version info:

```
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.0",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "a479a2a7fce0389512d6a9361301708b92dff667",
    "build_date" : "2020-08-11T21:36:48.204330Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
```

Has anyone ever run into this? Is there something glaringly obvious I am missing here? It's confusing since it works fine with slop, but otherwise doesn't even return a highlight entry in the result. No other question / solution I've seen to date seems to be relevant to this problem.

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior described above. Would love to see if there's a good explanation of what may be happening over here.